# Replacement for gluPerspective (with glFrustrum)

Tags: c++, opengl

How would you convert a gluPerspective function to glFrustum?  I have tried to use this equation, but have not had any luck as it did not generate the same image as it did with gluPerspective.

> top = tan(fov*3.14159/360.0) * near
>   bottom = -top
>
> left = aspect * bottom
>   right = aspect * top

I can't seem to convert my field of view correctly. Say, for example, if my FOV was 45, what would be the 'top' param in the Frustum call?

Comment: If you are expecting `fov*3.14159/360.0` to convert from degrees to radians, it won't work. To convert from degrees to radians, use: `fov*3.14159/180.0`.

Comment: thank you Ryan I used 180 instead of 360 it seemed a lot better but the picture still seemed further away that it was originally

Comment: See the link in tiguero's answer, it explains why 180 can be reduced to 360 for this case.

Comment: @JohnLam you need half the size for ur clipping planes on top of the conversion degree to radian

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Here we go - you can use the following method as a replacement of the `gluPerspective`:

```
void perspectiveGL( GLdouble fovY, GLdouble aspect, GLdouble zNear, GLdouble zFar )
{
    const GLdouble pi = 3.1415926535897932384626433832795;
    GLdouble fW, fH;

    //fH = tan( (fovY / 2) / 180 * pi ) * zNear;
    fH = tan( fovY / 360 * pi ) * zNear;
    fW = fH * aspect;

    glFrustum( -fW, fW, -fH, fH, zNear, zFar );
}
```

You can find some more explanation of the code on the [nehe](http://nehe.gamedev.net/article/replacement_for_gluperspective/21002/) page.